# How to position render icon on top of TextInput in react native

Tags: react-native, jsx

I'm having password field with eye icon on top of it. The problem is that TouchableOpacity with eye icon is rendered behind text input, so it's not visible. I've tried to use zIndex but it doesn't change anything.
Any suggestion how to fix this?

component:

```
<View style={styles.passwordFieldView}>
 <TextInput
   placeholder="Password"
   secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
   style={{ ...styles.textInput, ...styles.passwordInput }}
   value={password}
   onFocus={() => hideErrorAction()}
   onChangeText={(value) => setPassword(value)}
 />
 <TouchableOpacity
   onPress={onEyeClick}
   style={{ ...styles.eyeIcon}}>
   <View>
     <FeatherIcon name="eye" style={{ color: iconColor }} size={20} />
   </View>
 </TouchableOpacity>
</View>;
```

Styles:

````
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    textInput: {
        flex: 1,
        color: colors.lightGray,
        marginBottom: 10,
        height: 50,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 10,
        marginTop: 10,
        borderColor: 'lightgray',
        fontSize: 15,
        paddingLeft: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 0,
          height: 1,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.1,
        shadowRadius: 0.41,
        elevation: 2,
      },
    eyeIcon: {
        position: 'absolute',
        padding: 15,
        paddingTop: 20,
        alignSelf: "flex-end"
    },
    passwordContainer: {
        margin: 0,
        alignSelf: 'stretch'
    },
    passwordInput: {
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        marginTop: 20,
    },
    passwordFieldView: {
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
});```
````

Comment: You might need to set a left or a right attribute to the eyeIcon.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your idea or maybe my question was not clear enough. My problem is that icon is behind TextInput. I don't want to move it to be on the right side of TextInput. I want it to be on the top of TextInput, not behind, e.g. like here https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqWot.png

Comment: Got it. Check whether zIndex would work for you.

Comment: zIndex was the first thing that I was thinking of, but for some reason it doesn't work.